# Why would Assembly.LoadFrom throw FileNotFoundException only on 1 of 2 servers?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, filenotfoundexception, system.reflection

A `FileNotFoundException` was caught when running the following two lines of code:

```
string strFileName = "C:\\projects\\projectname\\bin\\release\\assemblyDLLFolder\\foo.dll";
Assembly AddinAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(strFileName);
```

> Message: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\projects\projectname\bin\release\assemblyDLLFolder\foo.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>       The exception is only thrown on one of two servers.

On one server the program executes with no errors. On a different server the exception is thrown and the program doesn’t execute.

What would make this occur on only 1 server?

Comment: Maybe the path only exists on one server but not on the other?

Comment: Did you check that the file is actually there and accessible? As well as all necessary references.

Comment: At a guess, either the assembly is missing, or one of the assemblies it depends on is missing....

Comment: Did you try to use Fuslogvw.exe to examine this problem? See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Check permissions of IIS's AppPool on that folder on both servers

Comment: Yes the dll file is located on both servers; the file & folder structure is the same on both. I'll try Fuslogvw.exe & check the AppPool.

Answer (score 1):

Not to be all Roy Trenneman about it, but have you tried turning it on and off again?

I ran into a similar problem a week or so ago with a Powershell packaging script that used Assembly.LoadFrom to load DotNetZip, and it suddenly stopped working on my local machine. Paths hadn't changed, and the file was there. What made it worse was that copying the .DLL from the path it was on over to C:\Temp\ allowed it to load just fine. It just couldn't find that file in the original directory. Even listing the files in the directory showed it was there, but Assembly.LoadFrom just couldn't load it.

Finally got sick of it and restarted the system, and it suddenly worked.